# Show quartic polynomial has no real solutions

Tags: polynomials, roots

To show a lower bound for the runtime of an algorithm, I need to show that 
$$
3 x^4 - \frac{64}{5} x^3 + \frac{192}{5} x^2 - \frac{192}{5} x+ 12   > 0 
$$
for all real numbers $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

I followed the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Nature_of_the_roots) instructions and checked the [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0747717188800154) they are based on.

With computer help it is easy to find that the discriminant is positive. Now comes the part that has me lost: 
Let $a,b,c,d,e$ be the coefficients. Then, according to both the paper and Wikipedia, the quartic function has real roots if both 
$$8 a c - 3 b^2 <0\text{ and }64 a^3 e - 16 a^2 c^2 + 16 a b^2 c - 16 a^2 b d - 3 b^4 <0$$
and it has no real roots if both are positive. However, the case where
$$8 a c - 3 b^2 >0 \text{ and } 64 a^3 e - 16 a^2 c^2 + 16 a b^2 c - 16 a^2 b d - 3 b^4 <0$$ is not accounted for. Unfortunately, this is the case for my polynomial.

I appreciate any help, including hints for writing such a proof for a paper.

Comment: Wikipedia says "If P > 0 ___or___ D > 0 then there are two pairs of complex conjugate roots". (Emphasis added.)

Comment: You can get a closedform expression for 4th order polynomial. Just find the expression for roots using mathematica/ matlab and show those have non zero imaginary parts.

Comment: [Wolfram-alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3*x%5E4+-%2864%2F5%29*x%5E3%2B192*x%5E2%2F5-192*x%2F5%2B12%3D0)

Comment: @tabstop: thanks, somehow did not see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Wikipedia mentions, in the case that $\Delta>0,$ then if $P>0$ or $D>0,$ there are two pairs of complex conjugate roots. Since $\Delta>0$ and $P>0,$ there are two pairs of complex conjugate roots, and can be no real ones.

Answer (score 0):

this equal to:

$15x^4-6x^3+192x^2-192x+60>0$
$15x^4-6x^3+192x^2-192x+60=(3x^2-8.702x+25.0905)(5x^2-6.83x+2.3709)+.5112$
$3x^2-8.702x+25.0905>0,5x^2-6.83x+2.3709>0 \implies \\15x^4-6x^3+192x^2-192x+60>0.5 >0$

$25.0905=\dfrac{14439589717}{57550000},2.3709=\dfrac{272893639}{11510000}$